# Updating existing WordPress using newer version of downloaded WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I had installed WordPress on windows and currently I am working on it. But I wanted to update it and so I have downloaded the newer version of WordPress and I am not how to update the older one using this newer version.. And mostly I am worried what if updating the older version will loose my current date.

How to update to newer version without loosing any data?

Comment: to update your wp site,  just copy all the file(except wp content folder and wp-config.php file) of new wp and replace older files with them. in sort dont replace existing site wp content folder and its  file and wp-config file.

Comment: As previous comment says keep a backup copy of your wp-content folder and your wp-config.php file and don't overwrite them.
Then you can overwrite all the other files in your current install with the files from the new version.
The database will be updated if necessary when WP recognises you have an upgraded version. but if necessary you can run it manually https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/update-db/

Comment: If u can just illustrate the steps that I have to go through in WordPress file,  would be really helpful for me.